# Terminate my application upon suspension of other application (process hacker v2)

Tags: c++

i had this simple code of unlimited loop in my console app. What i want is when i use an application called process hacker v2 to suspend the loop, it successfully stopped and if i resume it, it continues again. So what i want is how to detect or how to terminate my application if it gets suspended by another app like process hacker? what code should I apply to it? Is there a simple way to do it? Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{   
    int ctr = 0;
    int x = 1;
    while (ctr < x) {
        printf("%d", ctr);
        ctr = ctr + 1;
        x++;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Send signals from process hacker & and handle them in the script . https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_signal.htm

Comment: I have a trick to do this but not the best way. Assume there are two application A and B. Application A is running for loop as ur code but added checking of existence of text file (or registry value checking). Application B will generate the whataver.txt file.( or update regisitry value). Once A found the existance of file, break the for loop and go to another loop. Then If B delete the file,  A back to 1st while loop.     U  can use "goto " to handle this in A.         This only suitable for trick, not suitable to use in real application. Add Sleep in loop, so the checking not to frequent.

Comment: thanks to your efforts. :) am going to check your solutions :)

Answer (score -1):

The suspended application cannot do anything, including termination.

Comment: That's impossible. Try to look the incupdate software. Upon termination of it,  the action command will still execute even if it was terminated via task manager.

Comment: @itTech then the action is not part of the process you terminated.